I have a question of Prop.1.10 of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry
I have a question about last sentence of proof of Prop.1.10.
I think that by A($\bar{Y}$)/m $\cong$ k and dimk=1, height m + dimA($\bar{Y}$)/m = n + 1 $\neq$ n.
What is wrong with me.
Proposition 1.10. If Y is a quasi-affine variety, then dim Y = dim $\bar{Y}$
Proof.If $Z_0 \subset Z_1 \subset ... \subset Z_n$ is a sequence of distinct closed irreducible subsets of Y,
so we have dimY $\leqq$dim$\bar{Y}$. In particular, dim$Y$ is finite,
so we can choose a maximal such chain $Z_0 \subset  ... \subset Z_n$, with $n$ = dim$Y$. In that case $Z_0$ must be a point $P$,
and the chain $P$ = $\bar{Z_0} \subset  ... \subset \bar{Z_n}$ will also be maximal. Now $P$ corresponds to a maximal ideal $m$, so height m = $n$. On the other hand, since $P$ is a point in affine space,A($\bar{Y}$)/m $\cong$ k. Hence by (1.8A(b)) we find that $n$ = dimA($\bar{Y}$) = dim$\bar{Y}$. Thus dim$Y$ = dim$\bar{Y}$
1.8A(b) Let $k$ be a field, and let $B$ be an integral domain which is a finitely generated $k$-algebra. then
For any prime ideal $p$ in $B$, we have height $p$ + dim $B/p$ = dim$B$

Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax for formatting all of the math in your post. You've used it in a few places, like getting the over-lines and isomorphism symbols, but you need to use it for all of your mathematical expressions.

Here $\text{dim } k$ refers to the Krull dimension of $k$; (not the vectorspace dimension; which might be where you confused yourself). So $\text{dim } k = 0$.
